# Nginx rewrites working on local virtual machine but doesn't work on live server

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx configuration on a vagrant VM, where the site is running Joomla. This runs fine with no issues. The issue is with nginx on the live site, running the same version as on the VM - `1.8.0`.

When you visit the site on the VM, all URL rewriting works, but when you visit on the live site, none of the rewriting works. I can access the homepage so we know nginx works, and I can access the sites pages with `example.com/index.php?page=page1` but if I try `example.com/page1` I get `404 Not Found` where `example.com/page1` would work fine on the VM.

Here is the config:

```
server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name    example.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        autoindex off;

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name example.com;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access_log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error_log info;

        root /vagrant/site;

        index index.html index.htm index.php default.html default.htm;

        # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        # deny running scripts inside writable directories
        location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
            return 403;
            error_page 403 /403_error.html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

        # caching of files
        location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
                expires 1y;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
                expires 14d;
        }
}
```

The config on the live server is identical apart from the `PHP` section:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
       }
```

The error log simply states

> 015/08/25 18:58:21 [error] 35356#35356: *6432 open()
>   "/home/site/page1" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: 000.000.000.000, server: myflashstore.net, request:
>   "GET /page1 HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer:
>   "https://www.example.com/"

Comment: Share Nginx error log beforehand please.

Comment: @Anatoly I've updated with the error log